# Calibration of a spectrophtometer

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, concentration, spectrophotometry

In my lab, I had to use spectroscopy to determine the concentration of protein in milk whey from buttermilk and understand how absorbance of light is related to concentration (Beer's Law).

This was my data: The standards were dilutions.

Concentration (mg/mL) --> Absorbance

Standard 1: 0.4  --> 0.19 
Standard 2: 0.2  --> 0.16 
Standard 3: 0.1  --> 0.07 
Buttermilk: 0.6  --> 0.34

One of my post-lab questions was:

**Draw a picture of what you think your calibration graph (Beer's law plot) would have looked like if you had blanked the spectrometer with a tube that only contained water?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bioanalytical Spectroscopy](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48694/bioanalytical-spectroscopy)

Comment: **Do not** repost your questions! I can even see how you used copy paste

Comment: @Mithoron Not a duplicate - just a different question about the same prac problem, I suspect.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes, this is NOT a duplicate. I copy and pasted my data and what I had to do in the lab in order for people to be able to understand my question better.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal situatiuon, you might expect that at zero protein concentration there would be zero absorbance. This means your calibration plot should go through the zero-intercept. However, there may be a number of reasons why this is not quite so: your cuvette will absorb or scatter a small amount of light, your solvent may absorb light, there may be stray light, or there may be some other systematic error being introduced into the system. Running a blank sample of just water allows you to compensate for these systematic errors. The blank contains no analyte, but will still incorporate any systematic error, and so adjusts your calibration graph to compensate for these.

A couple of comments:

- it is unusual for you to have your calibration curve that contains concentrations that are outside the expected concentration of your real sample. This is not generally very accurate, as it relies on extrapolation of your calibration curve. Normally, one would run a series of standards that extend beyond the expected concentration range of your sample.
- A calibration curve of just three points is also not very accurate. Your plot is not linear (would you expect it to be?), but with only three points, it is not possible to know whether you have a random error, or your graph is in fact non-linear resulting from a possible concentration-dependent equilibrium shift or other chemical phenomenon.